# Vue.js: “data-v-<hash>” attributes for scoped CSS

Tags: css, vue.js

In `.vue` files, **scoped CSS** is a very powerful feature as it allows the  CSS to be applied on the current component only. Let’s start with an example. According to the [documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html), `vue-loader` will transform the following code:

```
<style scoped>
.example {
  color: red;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<template>
  <div class="example">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

into:

```
<style>
.example[data-v-f3f3eg9] {
  color: red;
}
ul[data-v-f3f3eg9] {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li[data-v-f3f3eg9] {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<template>
  <div class="example" data-v-f3f3eg9>
    <ul data-v-f3f3eg9>
      <li data-v-f3f3eg9>1</li>
      <li data-v-f3f3eg9>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

As we see, every nodes of the component have a `data-v-f3f3eg9` attribute. We already understand that in a big project, with multiple components and their own scoped CSS, we will observe the omnipresence of `data-v-<hash>` attributes. There are (I think) at least two consequences of such `data-v-<hash>` approach:

- In the race for the [best](https://goalsmashers.github.io/css-minification-benchmark/) CSS optimizer to get the smaller file, this approach ends up with very big CSS files.
- The efficiency of the parsing of the DOM tree must be affected.

My question is : **why Vue.js adopted this strategy** ?

Indeed, as each component template must contain exactly one root element, it can by itself define the scope of the CSS, having alone the `data-v-f3f3eg9` attribute. Moreover, it could have been an additional short class name, such as only `cf3f3eg9` (the `c` here ensures that the class name does not start with a digit):

```
<style>
.example.cf3f3eg9 {
  color: red;
}
.cf3f3eg9 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.cf3f3eg9 li {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<template>
  <div class="example cf3f3eg9">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

And we can more easily adopt a [rename](https://www.slideshare.net/basisjs/csso-compress-css-english-version) process for our entire project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your approach, specificity of selectors changes differently: the deeper the element is, the longer is its selector chain. Unequal specificity can open door to very subtle bugs - reproducible, yes, but still subtle. To add insult to injury, you won't be able to spot these bugs by looking at the code alone - you'll have to check the builds.

Still, if this is not a problem for your methodology and/or project scope, you can still employ this approach with vuejs-loader. Quoting [the doc](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors):

> If you want a selector in scoped styles to be "deep", i.e. affecting
>   child components, you can use the >>> combinator:

```
<style scoped> 
.a >>> .b { /* ... */ } 
</style>
```

> The above will be
>   compiled into:

```
.a[data-v-f3f3eg9] .b { /* ... */ }
```

> Some pre-processors, such as SASS,
>   may not be able to parse `>>>` properly. In those cases you can use the
>   /deep/ combinator instead - it's an alias for `>>>` and works exactly
>   the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ignored that ; could you please provide me with some example or refs about the very subtle bugs that unequal specificity can introduce ?

Comment: I have read this part of the doc you are quoting. It's closer to my approach, though all the child nodes of the component keep having the attribute `data-v-f3f3eg9` even if it is not needed anymore.